# PHP 4 Send email through SMTP

Tags: php, email, smtp, pear, php4

I have a PHP 4 code that needs to be modified to send emails through SMTP and I have already installed the Pear mail package on the server. It is Sevrer 2008 R2 64 bit. The problem is that it does not send any emails! what am I missing here?The Mail.php is located in a different folder than the actual website files so I had to specify the path in the "Include". The name of the file is Vistiro.php3: Please advice:

```
Function PostSlip() {
    Global $_parent,$_contact,$_problem,$_summary;
    $p_contact = addslashes($_contact);
    $p_problem = addslashes($_problem);
    $p_summary = addslashes($_summary);
    $p_now          =   time();
    $qstring="insert into slips (spid,o_date,status,priority,o_tech,problem,summary,is_public,l_activity,l_tech,ctag) values ($_parent,$p_now,'O',4,'$p_contact','$p_problem','$p_summary','0','$p_now','$p_contact','ANONYMOUS')";   
    $qhandle = db_query($qstring);
    $count = db_affected_rows($qhandle);
    $newsid = db_insertid($qhandle);
    RecalcSlip($_parent);
    echo "<tr><td bgcolor=#808080 width=100% align=center>\n";
    if ($count > 0) {
        echo "Thank you for your submission.<br>";
        echo "Your Slip ID is <b>$newsid</b><br>";
        echo "Use this number at a later date to check on the status of this entry.";

        include "/inetpub/PHP_New/PEAR/Mail.php";
        $from = "username@domain.com";
        $to = "username@domain.com";
        $subject = "Test email using PHP SMTP with SSL\r\n\r\n";
        $body = "This is a test email message";

        $host = "smtp.companyname.com";
        $port = "25";
        $username = "domain\username";
        $password = "email password";

        $headers = array ('From' => $from,
          'To' => $to,
          'Subject' => $subject);
        $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
          array ('host' => $host,
            'port' => $port,
            'auth' => true,
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password));

        $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

        if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
          echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
        } else {
          echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
        }

    } else {
        echo "An error occured during the update.  Sorry, please try again later.";
    }
    echo "<br><a href=\"visitor.php3\">Return to Browsing</a>";
}
```

Comment: errors? mail server log?

Comment: I have used the same exact settings on the asp.net application with no issues what so ever so I think it has got to do something with the code? any ideas?

Comment: ok but does it return any errors or? and what does the mail server log file say?

Comment: No errors and it even doesnt say it was completed successfully. It basically bypasses this block completely:  if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
          echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
        } else {
          echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
        }

Comment: sounds like there's an error then than your not seeing (or you would see some output). Is error checking and display on

Comment: Im sorry what do you mean by error checking and display?